# Mongodb - Multi-key index on array of sub documents produces strange explain plan

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

If I insert the following document:

```
db.test.insertOne({ main_data : 100, sub_docs: [{ data : 22 },{ data : 859 },{ data: 151 }]}
```

And create an index on it using:

```
db.test.createIndex({"sub_docs.data" : 1})
```

When I perform a query to try and match the data using:

```
db.test.find({ sub_docs: { $elemMatch: { data: { $gte: 110, $lt: 160 }}}})
```

Why does the explain plan show the index starting from either inf.0 or -inf.0 up to one of the bounds of the $elemMatch? For example:

```
"indexBounds" : {
    "sub_docs.data" : [
        "[110.0, inf.0]"
    ]
}
```

Why aren't the bounds "[110.0, 160.0]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in MongoDB 3.4:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15086